# Jenkins console output table in email

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

In Jenkins console output the below table will be displayed. The no of rows will vary based on the build output. The table starts with Summary: and ends with "Total" followed with the "=" symbol line.

```
Summary:
------------
|Row1
------------
|Row2
============
Total
============
```

we are using [email-ext](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin) plugin. How to include this table in email using ${BUILD_LOG_REGEX} or ${BUILD_LOG_EXCERPT}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the regex to include the table in the email.

```
<pre>${BUILD_LOG_REGEX, regex="^-+$|^=+$", linesBefore=1, showTruncatedLines=false }</pre>
```

The Lines starting with `-` and `=` are matched with regex and `linesBefore=1` fetched the lines starting with `|` and `showTruncatedLines=false` removed all the unwanted contents. Only the table format displayed in email.

Comment: Please mark this answer, as the actual answer to your question. Thanks!